# Optimizing R scripts performing binomial calculations

Tags: php, r

I'm trying to plot binomial curves using R scripts which are executed by PHP loops. The scripts are taking a very long time to run and I want to improve the algorithm to run faster.

The input values are:

```
$xmax = 360;
$p = 0.975;
$prvn = 1;
$b = 1.7;
$c = 0.995;
```

The PHP function called for each loop is:

```
function cg_graphs_get_binomial($xmax, $p, $prvn = 1, $b = 1.7, $c = 0.99){

  $Alert = array();
  /*run the Rscript file located in the module root*/
  $Rgennloc = "/home/rcstest/www/".drupal_get_path('module', 'cg_graphs')."/Rbinomgenn.R"; //Rscript file location
  $Rbinomloc = "/home/rcstest/www/".drupal_get_path('module', 'cg_graphs')."/Rbinomnew.R"; //Rscript file location

  for($i = 0; $i <= $xmax; $i++){
    exec("Rscript --slave ".$Rgennloc." ".$prvn." ".$i." ".$b, $n);
    $ne = explode('[1]', $n[$i]);
    $prvn = $ne[1];
    exec("Rscript --slave ".$Rbinomloc." ".$prvn." ".$p." ".$c, $alert);
    $at = explode('[1]', $alert[$i]);
    $Alert[] = trim($at[1]);
  }

  return $Alert; //return the data array
```

The first R script called ($Rgennloc) generates the n value, based on the n value of the previous loop, or 1 if it is the first loop. This increments as follows (etc):

1
6
16
32
53
80

The first r script looks like this and runs in relatively short amount of time:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
#grab args as passed into via CLI
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

#R script to generate n value

#implimentation of excel ROUNDDOWN function
ROUNDDOWN <- function(.number, .num_digits){
    return(as.integer(.number*10^.num_digits)/(10^.num_digits))
}

#generate n
n <- function(.prvn, .xaxis, .B){
    return(.prvn + ROUNDDOWN(.xaxis * exp(1)^.B, 0))
}

#wrapper function
n(as.integer(args[1]), as.integer(args[2]), as.double(args[3]))
```

When the second script is called, it runs quickly for about the first 20 calls (where n gets to around 1000 and xaxis is 20) but then it starts to slow down.

The second script:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
# replace '/usr/bin' with actual R executable 
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

#Critbinom - R implimentation of the excel function
CRITBINOM <- function(.trials, .probability_s, .alpha){
    i <- 0
    while(sum(dbinom(0:i, .trials, .probability_s)) < .alpha){
        i <- i + 1
    }
    return(i)
}

# Binomdist - R implimentation of the excel function
BINOMDIST <- function(.number_s, .trials, .probability_s, .cumulative){
    if(.cumulative){
        return(sum(dbinom(0:.number_s, .trials, .probability_s)))
    }else{
        return(choose(.trials,.number_s)*.probability_s^.number_s*(1-.probability_s)^(.trials-.number_s))
    }
}

# Iserror - R version of this, no need for all excel functionality.
ISERROR <- function(.value){
    return(is.infinite(.value))
}

# Generate the alert
generate_Alert <- function(.n, .probability_s, .alpha){
    critB <- CRITBINOM(.n, .probability_s, .alpha)
    adj <- critB-(BINOMDIST(critB, .n, .probability_s,TRUE)-.alpha)/(BINOMDIST(critB, .n, .probability_s,TRUE)-BINOMDIST(critB-1, .n, .probability_s,TRUE))
    if(ISERROR(100 * adj / .n)){
        return(0)
    }else{
        adj_value <- (adj / .n)
        return(adj_value)
    }
}

# Generate the alert for current xaxis position
generate_data <- function(.n, .probability_s, .alpha){
    Alert <- generate_Alert(.n, .probability_s, .alpha)
    return(Alert)
}

# Call wrapper function generate_data(n, p, alpha)
generate_data(as.integer(args[1]), as.double(args[2]), as.double(args[3]))
```

The xaxis value may get as high as 360, but the script starts slowing down before xaxis gets to 30. By the time xaxis is at 100 it takes some 30 seconds to complete each loop, it just gets worse from there.

What is the best way of optimizing this? I think its only using 1 core at the moment. I have 2 available but I'm not sure how much difference the second core will make in the long run.

I am using the latest version of R.

Comment: Without being able to help in the issue itself: is it wise to open a completely new Rscript so often? I would open a R-Server as a pipe and "talk" to the once created R-Server, and shut it down at the end.

Comment: that might well help, though its not something i was aware you could do with php :), do you have any suggestions on how to i could that part of the script?

Comment: Hm, my first guess would be popen. Vim can connect "interactively" to R, so there must be a easy-to-use Server-Mode of R. Sorry, that I have no Details, and good luck for the "real" question!

Comment: I don't speak PHP, but why don't you do everything in R and try do get rid of the loops using vectorization? You could also optimize some of the R function, e.g., your `CRITBINOM` function looks like it could be much improved using some statistical knowledge.

Comment: i.e., `CRITBINOM` seems to be more or less the same as `qbinom(.alpha,.trials,.probability_s)`.

Comment: Im not a statistician i'm afraid, i'm only doing that as part of a request from a client. is qbinom the -exactly- the same? i can't use something thats off slightly...

im open to suggestions on how to take this out of php and all into R :)

Comment: As far as I understand your function it is exactly the same (although `qbinom` might use a different algorithm internally), except in how it handles multiple probability values.

Comment: i'll try it, any other optimization tips? :)

Comment: @Roland qbinom is returning the exact same results :) so thats a good start! i will speed test now, hopefully a few more changes and we'll be going much faster :)

Comment: The main advice would be to avoid the PHP loop and use the power of vectorization in R. But again, I don't speak PHP and cannot help with that.

Comment: @Roland your suggestion to use qbinom has done the trick. the full data set takes about 8 mins to run now, rather than 7 + hours.

that's good enough for me :). would you like to put that as the answer so i can upvote and select it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment a bit, so this question gets an answer:

A `while` loop in R is a very unsual construct (I see it only once or twice a year in serious code). It's often an indicator that the code does not follow the spirit of R, but was written by someone with experience from other language (e.g., from the C familiy). `while` loops are very expensive performance-wise in R and if really needed should be better written in C.

Fortunately, the `CRITBINOM` function is just a naive re-implementation of `qbinom` (quantile function of the binomial distribution), which can be used instead. The only difference is in how multiple success probabilities are handled (`qbinom` is fully vectorized).

I believe a full reimplementation in R (avoiding explicit loops) could get this down to seconds or less, but I don't know PHP.